# return list of all unique states from table in greenDao?

Tags: database, greendao

i have a table called Branch in which i have 4 columns state,city,branches,address

### Branch

### state|city|branches|address|

how to write query for finding all unique state .
and it should be in form of List .
like List ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a raw query to do this.

```
public List<String> findUniqueStates(DaoSession session){
    String query = "SELECT state FROM (SELECT state, COUNT(state) as count from Branch GROUP BY state) WHERE count = 1";
    List<String> states = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor c = session.getDatabase().rawQuery(query, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            states.add(c.getString(0));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    return states;
}
```

Comment: I want to pass Context in place of Dao session but it showing error .. Help me out                                                                                                             public List<String> findUniqueStates(Context ctx){  //body }